# How to Restore SQL Backup within Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio, publish, restore

Got an SQL Backup file of database that generated via Visual Studio's>Server Explorer>"Publish to Provider"

but cannot restore that SQL Backup in Visual Studio's Query Window raises error:

Window title:"Query Definitions Differ"
Error Text:"DROP TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported"

so
how can I execute an SQL Database Backup File ?(generated using VS>"Publish to Provider")
thanks.

Comment: Has do you followed the steps like in this tutorial?http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/22/recipe-deploying-a-sql-database-to-a-remote-hosting-environment-part-1.aspx

Comment: Btw, do you want to "backup" your schema, data or both?